# ComboBox. Select item

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox, indexof

Load items to `ComboBox`

```
private class ItemWorker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}


bindingWorker.DataSource = model.Workers
    .Select(x => new ItemWorker
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        FullName = x.FullName
    })
    .ToList();
cbWorker.DataSource = bindingWorker;
cbWorker.DisplayMember = "FullName";
cbWorker.ValueMember = "Id";
```

How can I select item? If I have `Id` and `FullName` separately (The `Id` is contained in the `contract` and the name in the other entity). I tried like this:

```
ItemWorker item = new ItemWorker 
{ Id = contract.Worker, FullName = contract.WorkerNavigation.FullName };
cbWorker.SelectedIndex = cbWorker.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

But `IndexOf` returned `-1`. The values of my `item` and the existing one are the same

[image]

[image]

**Update**

DisplayMember "FullName" can be duplicated. But "id" never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

`IndexOf()` is looking for among its items. When created new item:

```
ItemWorker item = new ItemWorker 
{ Id = contract.Worker, FullName = contract.WorkerNavigation.FullName };
```

Both values are the same, but the memory address is different. One belongs to `ComboBox.DataSource`, the other doesn't. Therefore returned `-1`.

**Solution**

In my case, I did the next:

```
    public static string GlueTogether(int id, string fullName)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - id: {1}", fullName, id);
    }

    public static string Parse(string fullName)
    {
        return fullName.Substring(0, fullName.IndexOf(" - id:"));
    }
```

`DisplayMember` is like text `"Name - id: 10"`. And find:

```
cbWorker.FindString(cbWorker.SelectedText);
```

Comment: LOL, for some reason I didn't see that answer to self, but effectively the same root cause :-)  Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` is about the list *in the combo box data source*, the way you are finding the item results is a different object. What you have in that code snippet is the creation of a *new object* (`ItemWorker`) and then you are trying to "find it in the data source",  but it's not there as it is effectively different.

If the list you are using to "set the item of" is the same as your data source, you may find it easier to use `SelectedItem`, reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.8

I would be keeping a copy of the list produced in the `model.Workers.Select...` step and using that to "find objects in".